# Using $resource with $asyncValidators in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, resources

This is what I wrote but angular keeps complaining about the $asyncValidators telling me is {}. I do not want to work with $http nor with $q. This is the faulty code I wrote:

```
       .directive('checkEmail', ['toolBox', function(toolBox){
     return {
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
           ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailExists = function(userEmail){
             var promise = toolBox.checkEmailExist(userEmail);
             return promise.get(function success(res){
                      return true;
                    }, function error(res){
                      return false;
                    });
           };
        }
     };
   }])
```

Has any of you worked validation with $resource? Where I get it wrong? toolBox.checkEmailExist(userEmail) comes from a service that looks like this

```
angular.module('toolBoxService', ['ngResource'])
   .factory('toolBox', ['$resource','$log', function($resource, $log){
     var dataObj = {};

     dataObj.checkEmailExist = function(email){
           return $resource('api/users/email', {email: email});
       };

     return dataObj;
   }]);
```

and the form element looks like

```
<!-- Email field -->
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="userEmail">*</span>
  <label class="control-label" for="userEmailField"></label>
  <input class="form-control"
         name="userEmail"
         id="userEmailField"
         required=""
         placeholder="Email"
         type="email"
         ng-model="data.email"
         ng-model-options="{ debounce: { default : 300, blur: 0 }}"
         check-email>
         </input>
</div>
<!-- Validation of the email -->
<div class="help-block form-error-messages"
     ng-messages="registerForm.userEmail.$error"
     ng-show="registerForm.userEmail.$touched"
     role="alert"
     ng-messages-multiple>
  <div ng-messages-include="FACETS/errors/errorMessages.html"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've came up with is this

```
// checking for email in the database
.directive('checkEmail', ['toolBox', function(toolBox) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.checkEmail = function(modelValue, viewValue){
        var currentVal = modelValue || viewValue;
        toolBox.checkEmailExist(currentVal)
                             .get(function success(resp){
                               if(resp.email == currentVal) {
                                 ngModel.$setValidity('checkEmail', false);
                               } else {
                                 ngModel.$setValidity('checkEmail', true);
                               }
                             });
      };
    } // end link
  }; // end return
}])
```

$resource is not working with the $asyncValidators unfortunately. Took me 2 days to realise this. I hope there was an answer, a more expert voice on the matter.

Comment: If you could find any other solution and you can share it would be great, but for now I have come to the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have to return the $promise attached to the resource instance object, rather than the object itself.

If your api returns an OK 200 response when the username *does* exist and an error status (e.g. 404 Not Found) when it *does not*, then the following approach works:

```
.directive('usernameExists', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function (userName) {
                return $resource('/api/Account/:userName')
                        .get({ userName: userName }).$promise;
            };
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it, it was matter of playing a bit more with promises

```
.directive('validateNbr',['$q','PreavisoService', function($q, PreavisoService) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: '',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.validateNbr = function(modelValue){
                var def = $q.defer();
                PreavisoService.checkUnitDigit({nbr:ngModel.$viewValue}).$promise.then(
                        function(result){
                            if(result.isValid === false){
                                def.reject();
                            }else{
                                def.resolve();
                            }
                        });

                return def.promise;
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

hope it helps